# How to check in SQL if particular value of a column is appearing more than once

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am trying this problem which I came across where I have to `SUM` the sales of a particular region and then one more column needs to be created as result by the name `stores` so that it can tell whether that particular store is in that region (East, West, North, and South) or not.

I don't know where to start
these are the two tables and the output:
[image]

Comment: It's considered very rude here to post an image of your data and results rather than text. Also, it means you're much less likely to get a good answer, because not everyone who reads Stack Overflow can even see your images.

Comment: Kindly share your data and desired output in text format

Comment: Oh!, my bad
See this is my first question.
I'm trying to upload the text.

Comment: What is your database ? MySQL or Sql-Server ?? please specify it.

Comment: I'm trying in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MYSQL, You can achieve your result by`left join-ing` `store_info` with `geography` table and `group by` on column `Region` as below. You don't need to `SUM` separately for `CASE` again.

```
 SELECT g.region,
       sum(s.Sales) AS Sales,
       CASE
           WHEN Sales > 0 THEN 'Y'
           ELSE 'N'
       END AS Stores
FROM geography g
LEFT JOIN store_info s ON s.SN = g.SN
GROUP BY g.Region
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

**Result**

```
region  Sales   Stores
----------------------
West    2050    Y
East    700     Y
South   NULL    N
North   NULL    N
```

You can check the demo [**here**](http://rextester.com/PJOMO66810)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT r.Region_Name, SUM(s.Sales) Sales,
     CASE WHEN COUNT(g.Store_Name) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END Stores
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Region_name FROM Geography) r
LEFT JOIN Geography g ON g.Region_Name = r.Region_Name
LEFT JOIN Store_Information s ON s.Store_Name = g.Store_Name
GROUP BY r.Region_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: In your question you are not mentioned the Database, So I added this Query in SQL Server version not suitable for MySQL. I removed the question tag `[sql-server]`.

Here is your Code (SQL Server Version)

```
SELECT GE.[RegionName] AS [Region_Name]
    ,ISNULL(SUM (SI.[NetSales]), 0) AS [NetSales]
    ,CASE WHEN SUM (SI.[NetSales]) IS NULL THEN N'N' ELSE N'Y' END AS [Stores]
FROM [DevDB].[dbo].[Geography] GE
LEFT JOIN (SELECT StoreName, SUM([Sales]) AS [NetSales]
    FROM [DevDB].[dbo].[Store_Information]
    GROUP BY StoreName) SI
ON SI.[StoreName] = GE.[StoreName]
GROUP BY GE.[RegionName]
```

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is SQL Server and Sales is a `NVARCHAR` column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Region_name], 
        ISNULL('$' + CAST(SUM(CAST(Sales as MONEY)) AS NVARCHAR(20)), '$0') Sales, 
        CASE WHEN SUM(CAST(Sales as MONEY)) > 0 
             THEN 'Y' 
             ELSE 'N' 
        END Stores 
FROM Geography geo
LEFT JOIN Store_Information sto ON sto.Store_Name = geo.Store_name
GROUP BY [Region_name]
```